# Boot from time machine backup

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, time-machine, startup

As Apple suggests, Mac running OS X Lion v10.7.3 or later should be able to boot from Time Machine backup disk. I followed the instructions on this page https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht202796. I hold down option key while it was turning on, the startup manager popped up but for some reason I didn't see an EFI boot option. The Seagate external drive used for backup is formatted to HFS+ encrypted. My MacBook Pro from late 2011 is running lion 10.7.5. I've tried to press command shift option period and that didn't work. Does anyone have any idea why it's not picking up the Seagate as a bootable drive? The disk utility actually states it's bootable.

Comment: Is it formatted on MBR or GUID? Most disks are shipped with MBR, so you need to change that at first format/partitioning. Macs won't boot from MBR.

Comment: @Tetsujin it is formatted on GUID. I formatted the drive using disk utility erase and it seems like GUID is the default map scheme when you choose Mac OS extended.

Comment: @JBis but Apple says you can at the bottom of this page https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201250

Comment: @Igor According to what?

Comment: @JBis sorry I accidentally hit return before I pasted the link. Please see above.

Comment: @JBis - sure you can. From the KB link above "In OS X Lion v10.7.3 or later, you can start up from your Time Machine disk, if necessary. Hold down the Option key as your Mac starts up. When you see the Startup Manager screen, choose “EFI Boot” as the startup disk."

Comment: @Igor  You are correct. Sorry. And thanks for teaching me something :)